# Installing numpy on mac with pip: "requirements already satisfied" but "No module numpy"

Tags: macos, python-2.7, numpy, pip, sudo

I have python2.7.8 on mac, things I did:

- `sudo easy_install pip` - worked.
- `pip install numpy`:

Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): numpy in /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python

[image: ddd]

I also did "pip upgrade numpy" - no luck. What's wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is a conflict of different Python versions.

I would recommend installing Python and all the packages, such as numpy, scipy, matplotlib, pandas, etc via [Brew](http://brew.sh)

See this tutorial: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/share/doc/homebrew/Homebrew-and-Python.md

You can verify which Python you're running with `which python` or `which python3` in Terminal.

This solution is more flexible and cleaner in my opinion than using Conda/Miniconda. However it is also a bit more lengthy to install, as you need to have Xcode, devtools installed to build everything

Answer (score 1):

In my experience on Mac (and other OS too) it is best to go with [Anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads) / [Miniconda](http://conda.pydata.org/miniconda.html). This is especially true for packages like NumPy and others from scientific stack.

While Anaconda is a full-blown distribution with about 200 packages, Miniconda  is just Python with a few basic libraries. The big advantage is that all packages install as binary. Further, it makes it very simple and stable to install multiple Python versions side by side. For example:

```
conda create -n py27 python=2.7
```

creates a new environment with Python 2.7. Activate with:

```
source activate py27
```

Now:

```
conda install numpy
```

installs NumPy cleanly.

You can do the same for Python 3.5 and switch between environments with `source activate`.

Comment: thanks mike for pointing out to this conda thing... but i don't want to make it harder, the final goal is to run PYGAME on mac - I m almost done. except that pygame needs numpy..

Comment: I don't think it makes it any harder. `conda` made my life so much easier. Depending on your internet connection, installing Miniconda and then NumPy and pygame should not take more than 2 or 3 minutes.

Comment: mm, i know it is a bit too demanding, but if it is so great, can you make youtube tutorial ? full installation for pygame using miniconda?

Comment: it would help others who find this question!

Comment: numpy is installed in other dir: /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/numpy . i m ok, if i can change path for numpy - how do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Could it be that you have multiple versions of python installed? What happens if you run python using the full path like this:

```
$ /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2
```

instead of just `python2`?

Answer (score -1):

After jumping from one stackoverflow answer to another I found the solution!

my problems were:
numpy at different location( actually at right, expected-to-be location). It was the IDLE that looks for its own default folder where python2.7 installed.

I checked that my numpy is working like this, run this script to check it is working:

```
import os
import sys
import pygame
sys.path.insert(0, '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python')
import numpy
pygame.init()
print "( using __version__): " + numpy.__version__
print numpy.version.version
user_paths = os.environ['PYTHONPATH']
print(user_paths)
```

sys.path insertion adds additional path to IDLE, so it knows where to look for numpy.
Then I check if numpy truly imported - i just print its version. Right now it is 1.8.0rc.

I want to find a way to avoid using this syspath insertion all the time.
So far so good - for now.

Answer (score -1):

I had a similiar problem with numpy. However, it was resolved by choosing the right environment. If you are using VScode, open the command palette (ctrl+shift+p) and type

> Python: Select Interpreter.

From there, try choosing the right virtual environment/Interpreter.